# While swiping between tabs, pointer event are caught by button on a tabs pane

Tags: codenameone

Buttons on tab's panes now fire an ActionEvent when swiping from one tab to the other, if swiping is started on the button.

As this bug just started to appear in a build I did yesterday (builds from around a week ago don't show the bug) I speculate that one of the last GitHub commits of **codename1/ui/Container.java** changing the `getComponentAt(int x, int y)` function might cause the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix in the `getComponentAt(int, int)` method in the last Friday release triggered this regression. There is already a fix in the git which should hopefully address this issue. We are still tracking another regression and might push the next update faster to address this.

Comment: For some reason I still have the bug in actual builds.

Comment: I'm actually building versions which worked fine before.
Having horizontal tabs, swiping right or left the swipe starts the swipe, but if started and ended on a button it's event gets fired.

Comment: OK I see a problem and I fixed it. Should be available this Friday